# Qual è il significato di "trinciate dall'antica" in questa frase?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> Lei ebbe posto nel seguito di lady Arabella che andava a messa per contraddire: scollata, con vesti **trinciate dall'antica** e il ventaglio in mano.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "trinciate dall'antica" in questa frase. Ho cercato il [verbo "trinciare" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trinciare/), ma non sono sicura di aver capito. Il suo senso in questo brano sarebbe "tagliare"?

Comment: Sicura che sia “dall'antica” e non “all'antica”?

Comment: Sì, @egreg, nel libro dice "dall'antica".

Comment: Più leggo queste domande, meno mi viene voglia di leggere libri della Banti. `;-)`

Comment: _dall'antica_ suona strano, non so se potesse avere un uso equivalente all'attuale _all'antica_.

Comment: @mario: Non so se sia la stessa espressione quella che appare qui: https://books.google.es/books?id=4BnPHstKiVsC&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22fatto+dall%27antica%22&source=bl&ots=C2hfWLQWt7&sig=C6P_VbFneUPDD4FELqEXuF2CHxk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVmOnb4YjLAhUJXBQKHc2PAW4Q6AEIKDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22fatto%20dall%27antica%22&f=true

Comment: @Charo, no, in quel passo è chiaro il sottointeso _municipalità_: _la nuova m. riguardò il progetto fatto dall'antica municipalità_, si tratta di un complemento d'agente retto come usuale da _da_.  Nel passo della Banti _da_ sembra reggere un complemento di modo, che talvolta è in effetti retto da _da_, per es. in _agì da galantuomo_, ma che ivi, a differenza di quest'ultimo esempio, sembra un uso ricercato ove si sarebbe potuto usare, con maggior chiarezza,  la preposizione _a_.

Comment: Tiro a indovinare: l'autrice intendeva *vesti dal taglio antiquato*, cioè in stile passato di moda.

Comment: @egreg: Come accennato da Erik, sembra che il significato di "dall'antica" sia questo: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/antico2/. Quindi non si tratterebbe di vesti antiquate, ma di vesti aperte dalla parte di davanti.

Comment: @mario: Come accennato da Erik, sembra che il significato di "dall'antica" sia questo: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/antico2/.

Comment: @Charo, potrebbe essere, mi sembra una lettura convincente. AAA+ a Erik.

Answer (score 2):

Conviene cercare l'aggettivo *trinciato*, che può significare sia "tagliato" sia "aperto". Cercando "vestito trinciato" ho trovato un dizionario parmigiano-italiano (https://books.google.it/books?id=NZ4WAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=vestito+trinciato&source=bl&ots=tCdFuAf--7&sig=OyijVXLPwp6AGtnhsvlHUGBHapk&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh2pSd2YjLAhVBFiwKHWYxDy8Q6AEILTAG#v=onepage&q=vestito%20trinciato&f=false) in cui si dice che *trincio* è «il rotto d'un vestito trinciato», cioè aperto in modo che sembri tagliato.
Poi, nella definizione del Vocabolario Treccani di *trinciato*, si fa riferimento all'araldica. Uno scudo trinciato è quello diviso in due parti da una linea diagonale. Ho trovato un elenco di stemmi (http://www.leonemarinato.it/famiglie.php?c=S&pg=10). In quello della famiglia Soelder c'è un guerriero con vestito trinciato oro e nero.

Per la descrizione di lady Arabella, se si pensa al *trancio*, a una veste aperta in modo che sembri tagliata, possiamo immaginare una gonna con una profonda piega centrale; se seguiamo la seconda ipotesi, la veste è a due colori.

Comment: Mettendo l'accento sulla A di antica un dizionario etimologico riporta "che sta dalla parte dinanzi", quindi probabilmente la definizione di "aperto sul davanti" è la più accurata. Anche visto il senso del resto della frase.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Interessante... Quale dizionario?

Comment: Come accennato da @ErikvanDoren, sembra che il significato di "dall'antica" sia questo: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/antico2/. Quindi si tratterebbe di vesti aperte dalla parte di davanti.

Comment: Il dizionario etimologico menzionato da @ErikvanDoren, http://www.etimo.it/?cmd=id&id=1036&md=6a5e224cf7a58d6f3ffb85e16cae171d, è quello di Ottorino Pianigiani.

Comment: Questa definizione di "antico" appare anche nel De Mauro: http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/antico_2